# Is it possible to detect uniquely-named files if you have the URL path?

Tags: url, curl, web-scraping, wget

Let's say someone has posted a resource at `https://this-site.com/files/pdfs/some_file_name.pdf`

Another resource is then posted at that URL, which we don't know the name of. However, the pathname is the same: `https://this-site.com/files/pdfs/another_unique_resource98237219.pdf`

Is it possible to detect when a new PDF is posted to this location? Or would we have to know more about the backend infrastructure? Keeping in mind that:

- None of the other pieces of the URL are valid paths, in other words `https://this-site.com/files/pdfs` and `https://this-site.com/files` both return 404 errors.
- The names of the files are unique and do not follow a specific pattern.

If this is not possible, what are other ways you might inspect the request/response infrastructure to look for resources posted to that URL?

Answer (score 0):

my first suggestion is to look if there is another page that displays a list of the resource available on the website, of course assuming the website owner actually provides such page

the other method would be effectively brute forcing all the URLs under that path. you will need to collect some SOCKS to use with your crawlers to distribute your requests among multiple IP addresses otherwise the server will probably block your IP address. should you be able to distinguish the minimum and maximum number of characters in the file names (not pattern, just length) this operation can be drastically optimized.